# Merging non-zero differing bytes in large files

Tags: files, iso, binary, merge

I am trying to a salvage an old scratched DVD by ripping it to ISO. I have two readers and created an ISO from each. Each reader is unable to read certain *different* bytes of the DVD and replaces them with 0s. When I compare the files using `cmp -l file1.iso file2.iso`, I see that certain bytes on the left are 0 while certain *other* bytes on the right are 0 (the corresponding bytes on the other files are non-zero). I want to create a 3rd file, say `file3.iso` that merges the non-zero differing bytes from the above two files. As an example, assume for simplicity that each file has 6 bytes as follows

```
file1.iso   file2.iso
---------   ---------
0           0
1           1
2           0
3           0
0           4
0           5
```

`file3.iso` should be as follows:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

The files are quite large (around 8GB). Each file has the same number of bytes. I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Can anyone suggest the easiest way to do what I want. I can use the output of `cmp -l` as intermediate data but want to avoid writing code.

Comment: Are there any non-zero bytes that differ? say in file1.iso you have a 0x1 while in file2.iso you have a 0x2

Comment: Which tool did you use to read from the DVD disk (and write to iso files)? `ddrescue` in the program package `gddrescue` is a good alternative. See the info page [`info ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Optical-media). There is also `dvdisaster`. These programs may give you better data than you have now.

Comment: @wjandrea No. Only zero bytes differ.

Comment: @sudodus I used "disks" program to rip the DVD. I will look at ddrescue. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Good luck with `ddrescue`:-) and please let us know about your progress.

Comment: @wjandrea In a different disk, I did get that issue. What would that imply?

Comment: @Jus12 I'm not sure, just thinking it would make the task of merging them more complicated. Like if you look at my answer, the script errors if that happens.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Python script for you.

```python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''
Given two input files and one output file, merge the input files on
matching bytes or bytes that are null in one file but not the other.
Non-matching non-null bytes will raise a ValueError.
'''

import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]

file1 = open(args[0], 'rb')
file2 = open(args[1], 'rb')
file_out = open(args[2], 'wb')

def get_bytes(file):
    '''Return a generator that yields each byte in the given file.'''
    def get_byte():
        return file.read(1)
    return iter(get_byte, b'')

for i, (byte1, byte2) in enumerate(zip(get_bytes(file1), get_bytes(file2))):
    if byte1 == byte2:
        byte_out = byte1
    elif ord(byte1) == 0:
        byte_out = byte2
    elif ord(byte2) == 0:
        byte_out = byte1
    else:
        msg = 'Bytes at {:#x} are both non-zero and do not match: {}, {}'
        raise ValueError(msg.format(i, byte1, byte2))
    file_out.write(byte_out)
```

Make it executable then call it like so:

```
$ ./test.py file1.iso file2.iso file3.iso
```

Or for short:

```
$ ./test.py file{1,2,3}.iso
```

P.s. I've recently been studying reading files in different ways, so this is nice serendipity.